# Create an email service in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I try to make a service in my Symfony Sonata bundle to send an email to a specific person as soon as an order is created. The person to whom the email is send is the person the user select to approve the order.

I try to follow the [service container documentation on Symfony's website](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html), but it feels too incomplete for me. I want to see a complete example and not just a few snippets.

**This is my email service class so far;**

```
<?php

namespace Qi\Bss\BaseBundle\Lib\PurchaseModule;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

/**
 * 
 */
class Notifier 
{
    /**
     * Service container
     * @var type 
     */
    private $serviceContainer;


    public function notifier($subject, $from, $to, $body) {
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setBody($body)
        ;
        $this->serviceContainer->get('mailer')->send($message);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the sales order exporter object
     * @param type $serviceContainer
     */
    public function setServiceContainer($serviceContainer)
    {
        $this->serviceContainer = $serviceContainer;
    }
}
```

---

**My service inside my services.yml file looks like this;**

```
bss.pmod.order_notifier:
    class: Qi\Bss\BaseBundle\Lib\PurchaseModule\Notifier
    arguments: ["@mailer"]
```

---

**And when I call the service in a controller action I use this line;**

```
$this->get('bss.pmod.order_notifier')->notifier();
```

---

**The error I'm getting state;**

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   Qi\Bss\FrontendBundle\Controller\PmodOrderController::$serviceContainer

Like I said before, I've looked at the [service container documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) but I can't understand it.

Can someone please help me with a nice full example explaining everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `setServiceContainer` method in your service class, instead of it you should have `__construct` accepting mailer as first argument:

```
class Notifier 
{
    protected $mailer;

    public function __construct($mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function notifier() {
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Simon Koning')
            ->setFrom('noreply@solcon.nl')
            ->setTo('simon@simonkoning.co.za')
            ->setBody('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')
        ;
        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i finally see what's going on in the documentation as well. Some silly stuff that I can't always see at first, and then afterwards I feel so stupid. Thanks!

Comment: Now that you are passed this step the next stage might be to build an event listener and have your controller send an event whenever an order is created.  The listener can then take care of sending the email as well as doing anything else that might need to be done when an order is created.  This simplifies your controller and helps isolate your business logic.  Not required of course but something to think about,

Comment: And now you can add for example another dependency to your constructor: `@templating` to be able to send `HTML` emails.

Comment: @KamilAdryjanek That's exactly what I want to do next. I have a pretty good idea now.